# Cleaning up delegates in non UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying something different than the traditional examples for iOS/Swift code. Typically I see the delegate methods being handled in the `UIViewController` subclasses.  What I wanted to try was to keep some of the business logic out of the view controller in it's own Logic class that the `UIViewController` would use instead.  For example:

```
class LocationLogic : NSObject {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    var locationLogicDelegate: LocationLogicDelegate?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func checkWhenInUseLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func startUpdatingLocation() {
        manager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }
    
    func stopUpdatingLocation() {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    deinit {
        println("deinit LocationLogic")
        manager.delegate = nil
    }
}
```

In the init() method of LocationLogic, I set its class as the delegate.  My first question is, do I need to clean up the delegate at all later?  I remember reading about circular references but was not sure if this applied.  If so, how do I clean it up?  I tried cleaning it up in the deinit closure, but what's weird is, in my subclass of `UIViewController`

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
   var locationLogic = LocationLogic()
}
```

locationLogic is a property on `TestViewController` and when `TestViewController` gets pushed on the stack, I immediately see my "deinit LocationLogic" message getting printed.

So if I need to clean up the delegate, how do I clean it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the document you will find that
This is the `delegate` property

```
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate!
```

It is **unowned** property, so it is safe. It will not result in circular references.

So, you do not need to clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a separate object as a delegate, you can keep a strong reference to it from inside the view controller. The delegate itself, however, should have no strong references to the view or whatever object it is delegating for.

In your example above, the `TestViewController` should have the `manager` and the `locationLogic` as its properties. You then do something like this from inside TestViewController:

```
self.manager.delegate = self.locationLogic
```

You don't need a `CLLocationManager` object inside `LocationLogic` because iOS passes the location manager object to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` functions when they are called.